# Would potential energy be destroyed if the earth suddenly vanished?

Tags: energy, potential-energy

I know that energy can not be destroyed, only transformed into another form of energy, but I am trying to understand this case:

I throw a baseball directly up, leading to potential energy being stored. Then suddenly, the Earth vanishes (Maybe all of its particles decide to quantum tunnel to the other side of the universe at once OR it disappears in some other way like a collision with anti-matter).

Now there is no potential energy in the baseball. Where did it go?

Comment: You can handle the Earth vanishing but not the potential energy? (and a collision with antimatter does not count as vanishing) The potential energy belongs to the gravitational field of the Earth-basketball system, it isn't stored in the basketball.

Comment: *"Where did it go?"* - in the ashcan to remain with the laws of physics (as we know them) that you threw there.

Comment: It is not impossible to quantum tunnel someplace else, just very impropable. But it don't think it requires to throw the laws of physics into the ashcan!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you throw the baseball up, not only does it go up say: 8 feet, but the earth goes down some tiny tiny distance (for giggles, lets say 1/1,000,000th of a milometer).

When the ball falls back to the earth, it pulls the earth back up with it.

If the Earth vanished, or the ball vanished, then the potential energy is lost, but the kinetic effect remains. Wherever the earth appears, it will appear 1/1,000,000th of a milometer away from where it would have otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

The radiation moving away from the now disintegrated earth will have slightly less energy than if the ball were not there. The difference in amount, when the radiation reaches infinity, is exactly the amount of potential energy. The energy is lost in escaping the gravitational field of the ball. (I am assuming here that the ball does not move in the meantime, a bad assumption, but to illustrate the point.